# MKOverlay Vector Data Drawn Multiple Times or Clipped with drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext

Tags: ios, vector, mkoverlay

I'm using the method `- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoom inContext:(CGContextRef)context` to render a vector-based map for an MKOverlay on iOS.

I can't find a good way to avoid rending all of the vector shapes multiple times without clipping them to the mapRects (tiles) sent to the above drawMapRect... method. Let me explain...

drawMapRect... gets called on the MKOverlayRenderer/View multiple times when the overlay needs to be drawn. It gets called for various small mapRect tiles concurrently. There are two kinds of vector shapes that don't work well with this way of doing things, and therefore two problems that I've yet to overcome:

1. A small shape that technically fits entirely within one of the mapRect tiles but for which the actual drawn rendering should extend beyond that tile's boundary. Eg, a dot is drawn larger than the actual (zero) size of the point that it represents and often has a textual label associated with it that extends well beyond the mapRect tile. In such cases, they will be clipped by the tile boundaries. Currently, I get around this by drawing the entire set of vector data for every tile (ie, every time the drawMapRect... method is called). This looks nice, but is a massive waste of resources and slows things down a lot.
2. A large shape that intersects many tiles will get drawn multiple times - once for each mapRect tile for which the drawMapRect... method is called. I can (partially) get around this by drawing only the shapes that intersect the passed-in mapRect tile, but then I have the problem (1) above. It is a massive waste of resources to draw a large complicated vector shape many times when it only needs to appear on the screen once.

In the end, I want to draw everything only once, and not to have things clipped to mapRect tiles. Drawing everything multiple times can really slow things down for a large and complex set of vector data.

I don't want to have to repeatedly pre-render screenfuls of the vector data every time the map is panned or zoomed.  There's got to be a 'correct' way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

How should I go about this?

**In particular, is there a way to avoid having the drawing into the CGContext clipped to the mapRect tile that is sent to the drawMapRect... method?**

Comment: I have the same questions.  There are lots of great ways of using the drawMapRect for image based overlays; but for lots of vectors, it would be painful to have to redraw the entire line for every tile it intersects.  Just building that index is prohibitively slow.  I concur with the OP, there's got to be a 'correct' way to do this.